# glyphicon- the icon doesn't work

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have to use the glyphicon-calendar.
For some reason I can't see it.
I noticed that I got error in the `$(document).ready(function(){})`

[Attached jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa7u26f4/2/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: also, unless you're using the Angular UI Bootstrap library, please remove the `angular-ui-bootstrap` tag as nothing you've posted thus far indicates you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue initially and fixed it by downloading the latest bootstrap files which includes the glyphicon font.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download